# updating sign_out time into database upon user sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Am trying to update my database with signout time upon user sign out of the application but my solution does not work.

**Here is what I have done below:**

*So I defined a method which I call in destroy action to update my database with signout time but it doesnt work, rather it throws argument error.*

**update_method**

```
# the `save_signout_time` is what I have done to update logout_time upon sign out.
def save_signout_time(member_id)
  SigninHistory.update(
    logout_time: Time.now
  )
end


def destroy
  save_signout_time current_user.id
  clear_all_sessions current_user.id
  reset_session
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

What am I missing? Or how do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `save_signout_time` takes a member_id but then you don't use that member_id for the update.

If you want to update a single record the way you have it architected right now, you need to:

```
SigninHistory.update(member_id, logout_time: Time.now)
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, but saves nothing into the database.

Comment: Can you post the log file of this destroy action please?

Comment: When you say it saves nothing to the database how do you determine that? Are you running a SQL call? Are you using a rails console and fetching a signin_history? Also, I assume the behavior of updating a signin_history by id isn't actually what you want. Does signinhistory have a member_id column?